# Switching between 3 separate div and their contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the content of a div when a link in the submenu is clicked. Each submenu has a different content of div. I used JavaScript before with only two divs switching and it worked fine. I try to implement with three and cannot figure it out. It may be in the if-else logic in the JavaScript or something syntactically wrong with they way I'm calling the switching function. Here is the code for the entire page, css and javascript included. Any insight you can offer would be great! Thanks!

```js
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1, div2, div3) {
  d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
  d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
  d3 = document.getElementById(div3);

  if (d2.style.display == "none" && d3.style.display != "none") {
    d3.style.display = "none";
    d1.style.display = "block";
    alert("here1");
  } else if (d2.style.display != "none" && d3.style.display == "none") {
    d2.style.display = "none";
    d1.style.display = "block";
    alert("here2");
  } else if (d2.style.display == "none" && d3.style.display == "none") {
    d1.style.display = "block";
    alert("here3");
  }

}
```

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #DE001B;
  line-height: 35px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
}
#menu {
  float: left;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu li {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #303030;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  color: #DE001B;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu li:hover {
  background-color: #DE001B;
  color: #303030;
}
#menu li:hover a,
li:hover {
  color: #303030;
}
#menu li:hover ul li {
  line-height: 65px;
  color: #DE001B;
  border-left: solid 1px black;
}
#menu li:hover ul li:hover a {
  color: #303030;
}
#menu li:hover ul li a {
  color: #DE001B;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
  border-width: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 78px;
  top: 45px;
  width: 100px;
}
#menu li ul {
  display: none;
}
#menu a {
  color: #DE001B;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
#content {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#project1 {
  display: none;
}
#project2 {
  display: none;
}
#project3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  Welcome, User
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/65-256.png" /><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/46442.png" />Projects
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('project1','project2','project3')">Project 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('project2','project1','project3')">Project 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('project3','project1','project2')">Project 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/management-line/512/all_reports-128.png" /><a href="#reports">Reports</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="project1">
      Blah blah blah
    </div>
    <div id="project2">
      Blah2 blah2 blah2
    </div>
    <div id="project3">
      Blah3 blah3 blah3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions. I will try to answer them as quickly as possible! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What you want to achieve? after click the div binded to this menu position should appear and two others disappear?

Comment: Yes that's the goal. only 1 of the three will be showing at a time. We decide which one should be showing by clicking one of the submenu items

Comment: your problem is that when you try to access the display property of you element the result is an empty string. to actually grab the actual style of an element you can use window.getComputedStyle(element)

Comment: thank you @elio.d! Using window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("display") gets me the correct answer!